# How to add '19' to 69 in pandas dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, series

I have a column in my dataframe of year data(no. of items = 305) in 'str' format with year data 69,68,56...

All the data in the year belongs to 20th century.

I want to edit the column of year so that it has all four digits of the year

Can someone help me out in this?

I tried with creating a list of [19,19,.....] 305 times in str format and adding it to the main [year] in pandas dataframe, but it added 19 to the end of the string, the output i got was [6919, 6819,5619,....]

```py
#converted the data in year to string

df['Year'] =df["Year"].astype(str)

#created a list of 305 elements of '19'

df2= ['19']*305

#used add function to add df2 to df

df['Year'].add(df2)
```

I expected the output to be 1969 but I got [6919, 6819,5619,....]

Comment: `df['Year'] = '19' + df["Year"].astype(str)` should just work, also `df['Year'].add(df2)` did the opposite because your column was on the left side of the operand, you want `df['Year'] = df2 + df['Year']`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As your df.Year is already a string. Just prepend '19' to it

```
df.Year='19'+df.Year
```